# RGB LED - Colour Values

Tags: hex, arduino, byte, rgb

I have a series of RGB LED lights hooked up to my Arduino board, and I'm trying to change the values of the LED, only problem is that I cant seem to find anything on a HEX to RGB converter.

Also, the RGB values aren't like the conventional values you get like (255,255,255) = white. They appear to be in some type of byte format (0x0ff)? Which I'm not familiar with at all.

Could someone point me in the right direction in how I can convert a HEX colour like '9cb261' into an RGB byte value?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of RGB LEDs ? Are they just 7 colours ?

Answer (score 4):

Hex is just a shorthand way of writing the same numbers, in a format that's a little easier to read if you're concerned about which bits are set and which are not.

The number "255" tells you that there are 2 "100s", 5 "10s", and 5 "1s".  Put another way, it's 2 "10^2", 5 "10^1", and 5 "10^0".

Hex is the same idea, but instead of using 10 we use 16.  Since there might be more than 10 things in each place, we add the characters a - f after 0-9.

Using a short example, "9c" means 9 instances of "16^1" plus c (12) instances of "16^0".  This yields 144 + 12, or 156.

The "0x" prefix just tells you that the following string is to be interpreted as a hex string.

To break apart your example, the Hex color 9cb261 is just 3 bytes (9c, b2, 61).
If we convert the bytes back to decimal, it's (9*16+12, 11*16+2, 6*16+1) or (156, 178, 97)

There's a full write-up at [Wikipedia's Hexadecimal article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal)

Comment: Thank you - Is their a system in which I can convert, for example: 255, 255, 255 into the required format? Thanks

Comment: Here you find a converter from RGB to HEX:
http://www.javascripter.net/faq/rgbtohex.htm